# Build libnice version 0.1.5 and above on Win32

Tags: c++, c, winapi, libnice

I followed this instruction: https://github.com/jcaden/libnice/blob/master/README.win32 in order to port libnice on Win32. Everything works correctly with version 0.1.4. However, when I tried to port libnice version 0.1.5 and above, I encountered some errors:

- Struct **_GMutex** is an **undefined struct**.
- I can not find file: **inttypes.h**, which is included in **stunagent.c**

If you know how to fix it, please tell me.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked the same in libnice mailing lists as well and they have answered it. Hope you have ported the libnice version > 0.1.4 in win32.

http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/nice/2014-May/000846.html